# Why does Arrays.asList on an int[] return a List<int[]>, and not a List<int>?

Tags: java, arrays, list, arraylist

Consider this code:

```
int[] tcc = {1,2,3};
ArrayList<Integer> tc = Arrays.asList(tcc);
```

For the above, Java complains that it cannot convert from `List<int[]>` to `ArrayList<Integer>`.

What's wrong with this?

Why is it `List<int[]>` and not `List<int>`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An ArrayList can hold only objects not primitives such as ints, and since  int != Integer you can't do what you're trying to do with an array of primitives, simple as that.  This will work for an array of Integer though.

Comment: He could also do: Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3);

Comment: It is called autoboxing, combined with the varargs syntax ... so in fact you are creating an array of Integer here.

Answer (score 1):

This will work:

ArrayList tc = new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(1,2,3));

Comment: Maybe I'm mislooking something but I can't see the point. Assume I get an int[] parameter; what do I do with that?

Answer (score 1):

You could have it as:

```
List<int[]> tc = Arrays.asList(tcc);
```

[Arrays.asList](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList(T...)) returns a **List**, not an ArrayList. And since Arrays.asList is a [varargs](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/varargs.html) function, it thinks `tcc` is one element of a bigger array.

If you want to have just a List of Integers, you'd have to rewrite it as [SB](https://stackoverflow.com/users/263895/sb) mentioned in the comments for [Hovercraft Of Eel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5061983/arrays-aslist-screwing-up-in-java/5061996#5061996)'s answer:

```
List<Integer> tc = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3);
```

Alternatively, if you make `tcc` an `Integer[]`, you can still use your array as an argument in the following snippet by explicitly asking for a `List` of Integer, providing a type parameter that agrees with the passed array:

```
 Integer[] tcc = {1,2,3};
 List<Integer> tc = Arrays.<Integer>asList(tcc);
```

Comment: so what if you have an int[] parameter?